How to design Antenna for RFM69HW 433MHz on PCB?
I am currently working on a PCB with an RF module (RFM69), where I aim to establish an integrated antenna. The primary functionality of the PCB is to control a DC motor by processing commands received via the RFM69, such as speed control. The bottom layer of the PCB contains the motor control circuitry, while the top layer houses the microcontroller (µC) and signal processing components, including the RF module. I want to ensure that my antenna design is correctly implemented to achieve optimal performance. Below are the details of my design:

RF Device: RFM69HW-433S2R from HOPERF
Frequency: 433 MHz
Distance Requirement to the Transmitter (second device): ~10 Meter
Power Req.: Power of the signals are very important since the receiver is in encloser

Recommandation from HOPERF

Keep the antenna trace away from other circuitry and ground, a quarter of an inch
(6 mm), or more.
Antenna Length: Lambda/4 - 15% = 173*0,85= 147mm

(Hint: The length of the whip should be 10 to 20% shorter than the calculation, depending on the
dielectric and the thickness of the board. In most cases, 15% shorter is close enough.
see here: https://www.hoperf.com/ic/rf_transceiver/RF69W.html -> ANTENNAS_MODULE.pdf)
My Questions:

Can I simply create a 147 mm trace and connect it to the RFM69 ANT pin, or are additional steps required?
Do I need to create a ground plane? If yes, where should the ground plane be placed and is the size of the ground plane important?
I noticed some circuits use inductors and capacitors in conjunction with the antenna. Are these components necessary for this design?
In the below PCB screenshot you can see the ANT trace as horizontal, what if I would draw it vertically?
Can the antenna trace be covered with a solder mask, or should the trace be left exposed for optimal RF performance?

My PCB (Antenna Part)
Antenna Trace Information:

PCB Screenshot:
(the polygon is to create a restricted area (to avoid other traces and vias in this area)


Can I simply create a 147 mm trace and connect it to the RFM69 ANT pin, or are additional steps required?
Yes connect the trace simply to the pin.
I noticed some circuits use inductors and capacitors in conjunction with the antenna. Are these components necessary for this design?
Usually they are used for impedance matching or as a filter
Can the antenna trace be covered with a solder mask, or should the trace be left exposed for optimal RF performance?
You need to have the copper exposed and not covered so it can radiate properly.
